# FQL Query for friend_count has stopped working and gives error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

> fql?q=SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid='id'

I was using the above fql query for getting the count of friends. It has been working for me for quite some time. [Javascript SDK ]

But now it gives the following error message,

> {"error":{"message":"(#604) Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE
>   clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with
>   * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ",
>   "type":"OAuthException"}}

I tried copying this query and pasting it in graph api explorer tool and it works perfectly fine.

I have checked the FQL reference for [user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) and uid is still an indexable column.

I have checked the blogs for breaking changes, but there are none mentioned regarding fql. 
Any idea why this is not working anymore ? And any other way to get this working ?

Comment: This looks like the proper way to use FQL ! http://www.fbrell.com/fb.api/everyone-data. Shame on me for not knowing..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have a bad access token, or your query might have quotes around the numeric user ID value.

`https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid=me()`

{
  "data": [
    {
      "friend_count": NNNN
    }
  ]
}

`https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())`

{
  "data": [
    {
      "friend_count": 421
    },
    {
      "friend_count": 219
    },
    {
      "friend_count": 59
    },
    {
      "friend_count": 239
    },
    {
      "friend_count": 235
    },
    {
      "friend_count": 986
    },

**EDIT**

Based upon the code links you shared below, here's a way to get the fql url encoded properly.

```
var q = 'fql?q=' + escape('SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid=100001516911824');
FB.api(q, Log.info.bind('fql callback'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually since I am using a javascript sdk I don't explicitly  manage the access token. And doesn't the sdk automatically manage the access token ? anyways I'll look more into the authentication token.

Comment: I have checked the authentication token, by using getLoginStatus() and the response gives a valid auth token and also the status saying connected. I also am not using the quotes either :-) Actually this piece of code was working just a couple of weeks ago. Surprisingly using the Graph API Explorer still works, wonder what is wrong with the Javascript SDK. Just to make sure I also tried enabling the https for the web server, but still nothing. Worst case I'll have to rewrite the code to just get the response from https://graph.facebook.com/fql..

Comment: What browser are you using?  (Chrome, IE, Safari have built in developer tools and Firefox has the FireBug plugin) You can monitor your network traffic to see the exact call the FB JS SDK is sending as well as the exact response from the API.  Maybe your answer lies there.  :)

Comment: Wow ! That was a good idea :-) And I think I see the problem now, when I saw the request that was being sent it is truncating the =XXX. https://graph.facebook.com/fql?callback=FB.ApiServer._callbacks.f3a821a3bb1a5ba&pretty=0&q=SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid&sdk=joey

Comment: Wow I am jumping with joy !! :-) I replaced my query with fql?q=SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid%3DXXXX and it works :-) I tried encoding the whole string but it was giving some other exception. So do you think the FB guys need to look into this ? Actually I have already raised a bug with them, now if it is their problem I'll just update it otherwise I shall have to close it.

Comment: Can you run this query thru the javascript test console () or is it broken there too?  If it's broken there too, then it's a bug.  But if it works, then it's something on your side.  If it's on your side, can you post your code on jsFiddle and share the link?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b2sr2mv/JqtmL/ - I tried this code on the Javascript test console looks like an issue. I think i'll update the [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/170228089746280)

Comment: try running that piece of code here http://www.fbrell.com/ :-) I am new to jsfiddle so I thought I will use that instead of pasting that code here. after you run it just click on 2 and 3 to see the response.

Comment: See my edit to my answer above.  I found a way to url encode the FQL.

Comment: I wanted to point out that while this FQL query works, FQL is deprecated and there is no other way to get that information so, it would be best to build your application without this feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var query = string.Format("SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid=me()");
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.q = query;

            object data2 = fbClient.Get("/fql", parameters);
```